# Jquery-Dynamically select more than one option in multiselect

Tags: jquery, multi-select

```
<select id="program" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="movie">Movie</option>
    <option value="series">TV Series</option>
    <option value="episode">Episode</option>
</select>
```

In the above select, I want to dynamically select option movie and series.

```
  var options = [movie,series]
  options.forEach(function(e){
       $("#program select").attr('value',e);
  });
```

Above code selects only series option.

Comment: Did billyonecan's answer solve it for you?

Comment: yes it worked, I have accepted the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `selected` property on the options, rather than setting the `value` of the select:

```
$("#program option[value=" + e + "]").prop('selected', true);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LT48X/2/)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked. I had to include quotes to correct the syntax as below.                                            $("#program option[value='" + e + "']").prop('selected', true);

Answer (score 0):

[billyonecan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282196/746754) is correct. If you want more advanced multiselect, then see [here](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget). Demos [here](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/).